# POST запрос из файла

Tags: python

Есть большой POST запрос. Он находится в файле, хочу его программно отправлять через определенное время... Хочу использовать `Python` (еще варианты?). Как, собственно, отсылать запрос, который находится в файле?

Пример запроса в файле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запрос в файле находиться не может. В файле могут быть данные запроса. Если вам надо отправить файл серверу, то [в документации описано](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), как это сделать.

Comment: в файле находится сам запрос, со  всеми данными

Comment: Да? Ну ладно, пойду RFC [1945](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945) и [2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) перечитывать.

Comment: Покажите пример файла. Если там действительно полный запрос, то `sock.sendall(Path("request").read_bytes())` [Пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/1841962#file-http-post-socket-py)

Comment: добавил пример запроса в вопрос. спасибо

Comment: @theoff не добавляйте текст в виде картинки в ваши вопросы, это затрудняет поиск вашего вопроса для людей с похожей проблемой. Что у вас в файле лежит? Буквальная строчка выделенная рядом с `data` или полный запрос?